# JS bookmark to fill forms

Tags: java, javascript, bookmarks, fill

I want to fill in recipient and sender fields on this website http://sms.orange.pl/ using bookmarked java script. I have done some googling, and that's what I came up with:

```
$javascript:document.getElementByName("RECIPIENT").value='TEST';document.getElementByName("SENDER").value='TEST';
```

and

```
$javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].value='TEST';document.getElementsByTagName('input')[5].value='TEST';
```

Unfortunately both won't work. What's wrong? I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that dollar sign at the beginning there is unnecessary.  Try this instead:

```
javascript:document.getElementByName("RECIPIENT").value='TEST';document.getElementByName("SENDER").value='TEST';return null;

javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].value='TEST';document.getElementsByTagName('input')[5].value='TEST';return null;
```

Notice also that I added `return null;` at the end.  This is to stop the page from disappearing and just presenting you with the return value of the last statement, in this case, `TEST`.

Also, if you're looking for a more complete automated testing environment, have a Google for Selenium.  It's absolutely brilliant, and will be roughly a million times easier than making these javascript things.

Hope that helps.